# How Many Companions Was the Doctor Unable to Save?

Tags: doctor-who

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many companions chose to leave the Doctor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5392/how-many-companions-chose-to-leave-the-doctor)

I know that Adric sacrificed himself to save the Doctor and that the Doctor goes out of his way to protect his companions.  Have other companions died while with the Doctor?  Were any not self-sacrifice and, perhaps, a situation where the Doctor was just not able to save them?

(I know Rose Tyler was lost in another universe and Donna Noble had to forget her time with him, but both of them lived through all their encounters with the Doctor -- at least so far.)

Comment: Honestly, I'd rate Donna's sacrifice greater than that of death.  Take someone who was practically pointless at the beginning of the season, watch them grow, watch them become brilliant, and then take it all away... That touched me much more than any of the other companions.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but I'm pretty sure my answer in that question covers this (I can't think of anything to add to it, and don't want to just repeat it here).

Comment: Although I could add the short version: 6 died, 1 (Sara) was an accident the Doctor couldn't prevent.  (Excluding anything outside of TV episodes and the 8th Doctor movie).

Comment: Actually, Tony, while it's not a duplicate, one of the answers there answers this, so I'm deleting this -- I'll just leave it up long enough for you to get this message.

Comment: You need @tonymeyer to get the message to me :) (In general).

Comment: Adric did not sacrifice himself.

Answer (score 6):

[Katarina](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Katarina) sacrifices herself to save [the Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/First_Doctor) in *[The Daleks' Master Plan](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Daleks%27_Master_Plan)*.  If [Sara Kingdom](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Sara_Kingdom) is counted as a companion, she was killed by the Time Destructor in the same serial, which would also count as the Doctor just not being able to save her.

[Peri](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Peri_Brown) possibly dies and is resurrected by the timeline being changed in *[Mindwarp](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Mindwarp)*; alternatively, her "death" is a trick played on [the Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Sixth_Doctor) by the [Valeyard](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trial_of_a_Time_Lord) and never happens.  (See also *[Peri and the Piscon Paradox](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Peri_and_the_Piscon_Paradox)*.)

[The Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Fifth_Doctor) kills [Kamelion](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Kamelion), at its request, in *[Planet of Fire](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_of_Fire)*.

[Jack Harkness](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Harkness) is killed by Daleks and resurrected by Rose/Bad Wolf in *[The Parting of the Ways](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Parting_of_the_Ways)*.

[River Song](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/River_Song) sacrifices herself to save [the Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Tenth_Doctor) (an earlier incarnation to [one she travelled with](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Eleventh_Doctor)) in *[Forest of the Dead](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Forest_of_the_Dead)*.

(As per Daniel Roseman, if [Astrid Peth](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Astrid_Peth) counts as a companion, ([the Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Tenth_Doctor) offers but she never makes it on to the TARDIS), she sacrifices herself to save the Doctor in *[Voyage of the Damned](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Voyage_of_the_Damned)*.  Also, [Adelaide Brooke](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Adelaide_Brooke) does travel once in the TARDIS, and then kills herself to correct the timeline in *[The Waters of Mars](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Waters_of_Mars)*.)

Book companion [Roz Forrester](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Roz_Forrester) dies in battle in the book *[So Vile a Sin](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/So_Vile_a_Sin)*.

Audio companions [Lucie Miller](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Lucie_Miller) and [Tamsin Drew](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Tamsin_Drew) die while defeating Daleks in *[To The Death](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/To_the_Death)*.

Comment: Great answer, but can you add some links?

Comment: @Wikis Yes.  Yes, I can.

Comment: Really nice, now... :)

Answer (score 1):

Astrid Peth (Kylie Minogue) from Voyage of the Damned apparently counts as a companion, even though she never travelled with the Doctor. She sacrificed herself to save the Doctor.