# Who was the first Doctor Who companion to sacrifice themselves?

Tags: doctor-who

There have been various companions of the Doctor who sacrificed themselves to save others, most recently

> Bill Potts. The earliest companion I remember sacrificing themselves was Adric in Season 19 episode 6.

Were there any before that?

Comment: FYI, a summary of companion exits can be found in this answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5414/108

Answer (score 13):

First Doctor companion Katarina sacrifices herself in [The Daleks' Master Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daleks%27_Master_Plan); she is the first companion to die at all.

Comment: Also notable for being the only story in which Sara Kingdom appears.

Answer (score -1):

if you're only counting "actual" companions.. or anyone to sacrificed themselves for the doctor... there was ALOT.
just going for the rebooted series, "voyage of the damned" (10th doctor) there's Astrid
9th doctor-- Jabe, a.k.a. tree lady, gave her live so the doctor can save the space station from burning up from the sun.
also-- maybe technically the "first" is Clara, who was divived up across all of the doctor's timeline and died hundreds of times

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was specifically who was _first_, so unless you can come up with one earlier than the existing answer (First Doctor, season 3) this doesn't really contribute.